# TCP HTTP Gzip String Decompression C#

Tags: c#, http, tcp, gzipstream, pcap.net

I'm working on a project about packet listening. I got a problem with gzip decompression. There is the code:

```
private static string gzipDecompress(TcpDatagram tcp)
    {
        if (tcp.Http.Header != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = tcp.Http.ToMemoryStream();                
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[tcp.Http.Length];                
            ms.Read(bytearray, 0, 4);
            if (BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytearray, 0) == 0x8b1f)
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                zip.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder(bytearray.Length);
                for (int r = 0; r < bytearray.Length; r++)
                    sB.Append((Char)bytearray[r]);
                zip.Close(); ms.Close(); zip.Dispose(); ms.Dispose();
                return sB.ToString();
            }
            else
                return "";
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

it gives an magic number exception how can i fix that or am i on the wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing the first HTTP packet in the HTTP response, you should use `HttpDatagram.Body` to get the HTTP body in that packet.

If you're trying to parse other packets, you should probably first do TCP reconstruction before you try to parse the HTTP body.